# Firebase Account Linking (Email/Password, Facebook and Google)

Tags: android, ios, swift, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to use the linkWithCredential function from Firebase Auth, but I'm not sure whether I'm using it and understand it correctly.

We have a login page with 3 buttons in our app (Login with Email, Login with Facebook and Login with Google). When user login with any one of the providers everything works great (With every provider with its sign-in method).

But when user wants to login again in our app with a different provider we use the Firebase.auth.logout function and properly logging him out from Firebase.

It appears that we must need that the user will still be logged-in in order to link his account with a different provider.

Since user is not logged-in anymore I cannot use the Firebase.currentUser since it is null.

Do I need to get the current user provider by email, sign-in silently and then with that credential link it to the new provider? Also, it isn't clear whether we need to allow multiple account with the same email address enabled on Firebase console.

Is it possible to do that (linkWithCredential) without that option enabled?

Any help with examples on Android or iOS will be really helpful.

Comment: Myself I use the [FirebaseUI](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/auth)  to handle all this. FirebasUI is a user friendly  wrapper around the Firebase auth system